# Volvo V50 1,6 Diesel acceleration problem and total stop

Tags: diesel, volvo, v50

I own a Volvo V50, 1,6 Diesel. Just yesterday I experience this problem. When accelerating the motor does not respond fast enough and after a minute it stops totally. It’s -8 C. Can it be the cold adding to the motor stop not giving enough fuel to the injectors? Shall I change the diesel filter ? If that resolves the issue. Do advice what is the right way to diagnose the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you ever tried anti-gel supplements for diesel? It usually starts gelling around -12° C, but you really aren't that far away from that temp.